# What is the right strategy for me to develop a paid public wifi?

Tags: passwords

I want to establish a paid public WiFi system. Here is my model of how it will work:

> I will install a public WiFi in my apartment. Using the WiFi system is paid but, voluntary. Those who pay me a monthly cost will be able to access the WiFi. Those who don't pay cannot access the Wifi. Now, I cannot set one password and provide it only to those people who pay money as there is always a chance that the password will leak out to others who have not paid.

So, what is a solid security system so that only who have paid money can access the WiFi?

Comment: Something like [that](http://www.hotspot-software.info/myhotspot/en/index.html) ? *I have no ties with such companies, nor am I to provide any advices such as use or do not use it, nor do I know whether it is secure or not*

Comment: This should be in Security.SE, but look into WPA2 Entreprise, with an authentication backend such as Radius. Basically, each user has his or her own username/password, which you can provide upon payment, and revoke at the end of the subscription period.

Comment: Also make sure you are actually allowed to do this if you rent the apartment, it may be that your tenancy agreement forbids you offering a paid service in your apartment (which is probably not zoned for business to begin with).

Comment: WPA2-Enterprise with EAP is the correct way to go. Also make sure to put each customer in their own VLAN so they can't interfere with other customer's traffic.

Comment: Depending on the size of the network either for small get basic router that supports WPA2-Enterprise with EAP or if you want to go higher, above 30 clients you might want to get something like UniFi for complex control over the network

Comment: you could change the key each month and give it to those who pay, or have your "customers" give you their MAC (from getmac.exe or control panel) and white-list current accounts in the router setup.

Comment: @dandavis MAC filtering is a joke and can be bypassed in minutes.

Comment: @AndréBorie: can!=will... security needs to be reasonable for the task and risk, not objectively perfect...  people who pool a "wifi bill" can forge a MAC and network key? i don't buy it. back in college, i did something related and didn't even have the MAC option, relying only on "customers" not to divulge the key. it worked for years, no problem...

Comment: @dandavis we are on an IT security site, so using people's good behavior as your only defense is a bad idea. Also, what tells you that the attacker will be someone who just doesn't want to pay his bill and not someone evil who wants to eavesdrop on the people actually paying the bill? Finally, even if people agree not to reveal the key, if only one of them accidentally does so (compromised machine, etc) then everyone is at risk, where as with EAP only that customer is at risk since everyone has a different key.

Comment: in my experience, most consumer routers aren't capable of EAP, and it's not worth investing a lot for collect $5 a month from someone for something that cost you $2.50. the other part is the headache of administering the network (no matter the sec tech), and if that headache is worth it. OP: André describes a really safe way to go about this, if you can swing it. If not, then look into network _software_ and adding a 2nd Ethernet port...

Comment: This seems like a product recommendation question to me. Most hotels have systems like that. Hotel owners are rarely very IT-savvy, so I am quite sure they are using off-the-shelf solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use WPA2-Enterprise, it allows you to issue per-user credentials that can be revoked at will, in addition to using unique keys for each user (so you can't decrypt someone else's wireless traffic even if you are allowed to access the network, something possible with WPA2-Personal where the key is the same for everyone).

You'll need a RADIUS server which will handle authentication attempts (every time someone associates with the AP, it relays the authentication information to the RADIUS which decides whether to accept or decline the request). This server keeps (hashed) credentials in a database and you can add and remove them at will, possibly automatically by using a payment gateway. You can even serve a second, open Wi-Fi network which only allows access to your signup page (over HTTPS) so people can sign up and pay for your network by themselves without asking you. Once they paid their credentials are added to the database and they can connect to the secure network.